# Should we be able to flag suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, flags

Some suggested edits [occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/8069) are nothing more than cussing and swearing appended to the post. This particular example used a direct personal insult as his edit description.

This seems like the kind of thing where I would want to flag it so that the user can be stopped before attempting to vandalize hundreds of posts.

Since the edit was rejected, though, there's no easy way to flag it. Is there a good answer for this?

Comment: Good point, but I believe there is limit on how many posts one suggest to edit - 10 or 20 probably. Anyway, better request will be to block members with only 1 rep to suggest edits..

Comment: @Shadow: I like that idea. New users should need 15 rep, similar to answering Protected questions. At least they've wandered around enough and participated enough to muster 15 reputation points, giving some assurance that they (might) actually have a clue.

Comment: @Shadow, some of the most inportant edit some from experts that only visit SO to edit a few posts that point to their site/project/paper - we will loose these if not very carefull.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Your edit changes the meaning of the question. Don't change words within quotes, anymore than you'd refactor the code in a question on SO.

Comment: @Gilles, NO, it doesn't change the meaning, everyone knows what munged words mean, it changes the text displayed so corporate filters won't catch it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ability to Flag a User or Suggested Edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101538/add-ability-to-flag-a-user-or-suggested-edit)

Comment: @gnat, thanks, good call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest you flag the post that the edit was suggested on, and provide a link to the edit suggestion. Basically, treat it the same way you would flag a normal edit for moderator attention. Since the suggestion is rejected, though, the link to the edit suggestion is a must.

Note that because anonymous users can do this, there isn't much that can necessarily be done. You can't suspend someone who doesn't have an account, for an example. But putting these flags out can still help provide this data so that moderators can track any patterns or dangerous trends.

As far as the actual feature request, I'm ambivalent on it. Personally, I don't think it's wholly necessary since the scenario is already capable of being flagged indirectly.