# What is the proper way to alert moderators of an apparent spam account?

Tags: discussion, support

Reviewing suggested edits, I came about two suggested edits from the same account, https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/187748 and https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/187749 introducing unintelligible spam. Looking at the user page, the only activity from that account was suggesting such edits.

Since there's no flag button on the user or suggested edits page:

What is the officially approved way of drawing the moderators' attention to such accounts?

Comment: A related [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101538/add-ability-to-flag-a-user-or-suggested-edit)

Comment: @razlebe That's a good feature request.  Looking at the two linked suggested edits, there's currently nothing useful to attach a flag to since the spammer didn't have any posts of their own, and I can't get to the rejected edits from the posts themselves.

Comment: @bill I agree - see [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101545/137484) on that FR.

Comment: If they have any other posts, flag one of those posts with a custom moderator message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Meta post will do.  That user is <strike>now an ex-spammer</strike> no more.

Comment: That is good. In case of further occurrences, more meta posts, email or another way preferred?

Comment: I think what you mean to say is that spammer is now an ex-user. There's a high degree of recidivism amongst spammers, and that person is surely plying his trade somewhere else.

Comment: @DanielFischer Meta posts are fine for now.  I haven't seen this before, so hopefully it won't become a huge problem.  Still, I'd like to see the ability to flag a suggested edit implemented, as in the feature request that razlebe linked to in his comment.

Comment: @AlEverett I'm sure you're right.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone from refraining from the monty python references in this comment thread.

Comment: Seems like (s)he [moved to meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/177614/seexy-nadege?tab=activity) and started here, also on [Windows Phone beta](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/47), possibly elsewhere too.