# How to flag users with f-bombs in their usernames and no posts?

Tags: support, flags, profile-page, user-accounts, offensive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How should I flag a user account if it has no posts to flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128618/how-should-i-flag-a-user-account-if-it-has-no-posts-to-flag)

Lately I’ve been finding  users with offensive usernames but no way to flag this because they have no posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757954/fuck-you).  Should we flag those, and if so, how?

Some like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070579/fuck) do at least include posts or comments that can be flagged.  Yet given that there is no profanity filter in username selection, do we  then assume this is considered acceptable?  What about in the "About me" sections?  There’s some pretty vitriolic stuff out there, although also stuff that’s just using it as an intensifier, like [most of these](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+-site:chat.meta.stackoverflow.com+site:stackoverflow.com/users+-site:chat.stackoverflow.com+fucking+-reminder+-welcome&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Comment: see: **[How should I flag a user account if it has no posts to flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128618/165773)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/brainfuck (just saying ;)

Comment: I took care of the two you linked to.  Thanks for bringing them to our attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options:

1. Flag one of their posts (any one) for moderation attention and clearly explain why you are flagging.
2. If they don't have any post, flag one of your own (don't forget a link to their profile ;) *or* post the link to the profile in [The Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly), a room where a lot of mods hang around. Even if a SO mod isn't there at the time, any one of us can notify a diamonded SE employee via Teacher's Lounge and they can take it from there.
3. Well, as you'll find out soon, posting on Meta works as well.

Usernames and "about me" boxes are not treated the same, we tend to be a bit more relaxed about what you can write in your "about me", as the only way anyone will ever see it is by visiting your profile. Your username, on the other hand, is attached to everything you do on the site, be it posting, commenting or chatting, and it's a lot more visible. I'm surprised there isn't any profanity filter for it, and perhaps it's time for a [feature-request].