# Spam in About Me Section

Tags: discussion, spam, user-card

If a user has a link to a website such as www.enlarge-your-brest.com (no kidding, I've encountered some) in their About Me Section or the user card, should the moderation be alerted?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry

Comment: Also see [What is the policy on destroying users with very spammy profiles but have not posted spam yet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297993/152515)

Comment: Also [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles)