# How to flag a wiki edit that seems spammy?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

If I see a tag wiki edit that has a whiff of spam (or, at least, astroturf) about it, I can reject it. But how can I flag it so that a moderator could review the proposer's history and decide if, in fact, there's a pattern of promotion?

Here's a recent example tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dwolla

Comment: Linked, maybe dupe: [Should we be able to flag suggested edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80227/)

Comment: You have a linky?

Comment: I don't know how to make a link to an edit I rejected.

Comment: Is there a way to see my history of edit review?

Comment: [Here's your review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/131433/bmargulies?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Answer (score 7):

If you're really suspicious of them trying to introduce spam to tag wikis (or otherwise), you can always trot on over to their profile and browse through some of their previous suggested edits. If you see a pattern, I honestly wouldn't bother a moderator with it unless they're being approved.

Hopefully people can catch spam easily and reject it. After so many rejections, they'll be banned from suggesting for a week. I'm not sure much else is really needed on the part of moderation. None of their spam has really become visible outside their profile. The most harm they've done is use up a few seconds of your time to reject the edit.

As always, if you're *really* determined to have a moderator look at it, you can flag one of their posts (if they have any) explaining the details about their suggested edit history.