# Is it possible to flag a tag wiki?

Tags: support, flags, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to flag a wiki edit that seems spammy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147578/how-to-flag-a-wiki-edit-that-seems-spammy)

A user is currently doing her very best to get the research assistant. However, I just noticed that some of her edits are copy pasted from other resource without proper attribution, which hasn't been noticed by the reviewers:

- approved tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1394292
- non-free source: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1622404&seqNum=18

I've looked for a "flag" link/button, but I wasn't able to find one.

So is it possible at all to flag a tag wiki if it has been approved? Or should I just delete the old text altogether and put a "copied content" note in the edit message?

Comment: I think you just did.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: While this is true, I hoped that there was a mechanism which prevents me from opening a new meta entry for every tag wiki which contains vandalism/copied content or other flagworthy material. I'm still relatively new to meta, so if this is the way it works feel free to say so :D.

Comment: This is the usual way for folks who don't have enough reputation to fix the tag wiki themselves.  There are multiple guilty parties here (suggested editor and reviewers), so it's hard to know who, or what, to flag; you'd have to find one of the offenders' posts and flag *that* with a custom explanation, so I'd say posting here is probably the best way.

Comment: There is a more eggregious issue here - that wiki edit fails to talk about the HTTP header. It also fails the smell test when it mentions that content types are heirarchical - clearly it is talking about an implementation rather than the concept.

Comment: @slugster: It is referring to SharePoint Content Types.  The tag for http headers is [tag:content-type].

Comment: With a bit of HTML / JS trickery it is, in fact, possible to bring up the flag dialog for a tag wiki (since they're internally treated as posts, just like questions and answers). Alas, it seems that actually submitting the flag just results in a *500 Internal Server Error*.