# Tag Farming and non-valuable Tag Wiki suggestions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

I spent some time today contributing to StackOverflow by performing some review tasks. I noticed an unusually high number of tag wiki suggestions

- all from [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno),
- all (or majority) for tags very recently created by "Community" (< 1 hr since created) and
- mostly generic text that does not conform to general tag wiki content standards (like guidelines #2, #3, #4, and #5 here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)

In some cases I did in fact vote that the suggestion was too minor or not valuable, etc.. In same cases I approved the edit particularly if the tag had seen some real use (more than 6 questions or tag not created by community, etc) and the edit explained something to me beyond the obvious.

However, of particular concern were the numerous tags that were simply regular web technologies prefixed with 'drupal-'. For example [drupal-form-submission](/questions/tagged/drupal-form-submission). In this case the tag didn't mean anything different than regular [form-submission](/questions/tagged/form-submission) except that it occurred in a drupal website. What I really wanted to do was vote/flag the entire tag as not valuable/redundant instead of voting this particular user's suggestion as not valuable (although it was a generic description for form submission handling and not really distinct in any way).

In my opinion any question that was tagged with [drupal-form-submission](/questions/tagged/drupal-form-submission) should really be tagged with [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and [form-submission](/questions/tagged/form-submission) and no combination of the two should exist unless there was something substantially unique for that combination (which was not at all suggested by the very generic tag wiki suggestion).

I did search meta and found a number of meta questions ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165113/is-it-possible-to-flag-a-tag-wiki), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147578/how-to-flag-a-wiki-edit-that-seems-spammy) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58310/flag-for-mod-locking-etc-for-tag-wikis)) regarding flagging (mostly for spam), but none really address the idea of tag farming or tags that provide no value and are redundant combinations of basic common technologies.

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I just didn't see any obvious way of expressing my evaluation of that tag wiki in a totally satisfactory manor. I mostly had to judge whether this was 35% valuable (reject) or 65% valuable (approve, sometimes reluctantly). I never really felt a 100% for any of the suggestions.

I figured I'd open this for discussion on meta and perhaps see what the community moderators thoughts are for wiki suggestions and tags of a fairly generic nature.

Should I go back a remove the [drupal-form-submission](/questions/tagged/drupal-form-submission) from the 6 posts that use it and tag them with [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) and [form-submission](/questions/tagged/form-submission) and allow the auto clean-up to take care of the useless tag? When the clean-up occurs for a tag like this, do contributors to its wiki lose any wiki suggestion rep and/or badges, if previously "earned"?

Comment: What's your account on SO? It's not linked.

Comment: @Undo: my profiles are linked when I click on my name!? Anyhow [direct link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1002041/benswayne "BenSwayne"). Note 4 edits to the [tag:Drupal-Zen] tag and several edits to [tag:zen] tag - presumably +2 rep for each edit for this user? I reviewed 14 tag wikis in an 10 hour period (my day spans UTC midnight so 2 review quotas).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've hit the nail on the head with

> In my opinion any question that was tagged with `drupal-form-submission` should really be tagged with `drupal` and `form-submission` and no combination of the two should exist unless there was something substantially unique for that combination (which was not at all suggested by the very generic tag wiki suggestion).

and such advice should go into the guidelines for tag writing, if it's not already there (and assuming the appropriate place-holders are there for "drupal" and "form-submission").

So, go back a do your cleaning up ... if/when you have some spare time.