# Flagging question edits

Tags: support, edits, flags

From where can I flag edits made by a user with enough score to do so, but which not only do not contribute anything new to the question but also modify the meaning of it or vandalize it?

Comment: There is this feature request - which is specifically about suggested edits: [Should we be able to flag suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80227) Another related post: [Is it possible to flag an edit for abuse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5062)

Answer (score 5):

This will depend on reputation on that stack, but everybody can see the flag button, directly under the question body.

[image]

From there, flag for a moderator's attention. As it says, be specific and detailed.

[image]

Comment: That's what I did, that's why I was looking for an option from the edition itself

Comment: It depends on your rep on that site. If you don't have enough, that's all you can do. You don't have a rollback option.

Answer (score 1):

### Edits applied to the post

If possible, do a rollback yourself. For users who can only suggest edits, this has to be done manually. For all other users, there will be a "rollback" link in the revision history (click on "edited X minutes ago"/ "edited MM/DD/YYYY at HH:mm" to access):

[image]

(image from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/323179))

If for whatever reason you think this won't solve the problem (e.g., rollback war in progress, persistent problem over many months), please use the flag link under the post (near the share/edit/follow buttons) and select "In need of moderator intervention".

### Suggested edits

These you can just reject with the appropriate reason, and with enough rejections, the user will not be able to suggest more edits.

Comment: At low rep you can't get to that button, you only see 'Source, Link, Full.'

Comment: @Tetsujin "For users who can only suggest edits, this has to be done manually." This means copying and pasting the older revision.

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for disaster ;) I can see many an original being copied from the formatted text right into markdown, throwing it all away.